# Printing Nodes names in NetworkX

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, networkx

I have this code to plot a visualization to a Djikstra Problem.  I am having a bad time trying to print de node's label, like: A, B C, D...
The graph and distances(weigths) are ok!  I just need the node's label.

Can anyone help me?

```
import networkx as nx
G = nx.read_edgelist("edges.txt", delimiter=",", data=[("weight", int)])
G.edges(data=True)
edge_labels = dict( ((u, v), d["weight"]) for u, v, d in G.edges(data=True) )
pos = nx.random_layout(G)
nx.draw(G, pos)
nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos, edge_labels=edge_labels)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.show()
```

Comment: In the question, you say that you want node labels. But in the code you have edge labels. is it on purpose?

Comment: yes! i need them both.  I read the docs but no success so far to print the node labels

Comment: does this work? https://stackoverflow.com/a/15549916/3896008